Mosquitto Broker Sometimes Connects but Fails to Send/Receive Messages in EC2 Environment
I'm running a Mosquitto broker on an EC2 instance with the following setup:
ACL: Done via API on EC2 localhost
TLS Communication: Using self-signed certificates
Clients: Connecting from various servers, typically behind NAT or LTE networks, using the Paho MQTT v3 Java client library.
The issue I'm encountering is that while the connection usually works well, sometimes it establishes a connection without allowing message transmission or reception.
Occasionally, the client connects successfully (as shown by an established state on both broker and client in netstat -ano), but messages can't be sent or received.
The client sometimes calls deliveryComplete, but subscribers don’t receive the message.
The reverse is also true: connected publishers send messages, but clients don’t receive them.
Checked with tcpdump, and there appears to be traffic (possibly keep-alives) exchanged every minute.
I set max_message_queue_size to 150,000 on the broker.
There are approximately 500 clients, and all published messages are at QoS level 2, totaling around 35,000 messages per hour
What could cause Mosquitto to maintain an established connection state but block message transmission? Could the max_message_queue_size setting be affecting this behavior, or is there a specific TCP/TLS setting in EC2 or Mosquitto that could be leading to this issue?
Any insight into diagnosing or fixing this would be appreciated!

Enable debug logging in the broker. But there isn't really enough information here to answer the question. What QOS are messages published/subscribed at? How many clients, what messages rates, sizes? Do you know if you are reaching the 150k queued message size?

There are approximately 500 clients, and all published messages are at QoS level 2, totaling around 35,000 messages per hour. Each message is about 200 bytes. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find a way to check the number of messages in the queue. I’ll enable debug logging for further insights. Thank you

Edit the original question to add details
